# C# - Microsoft Access: Empty TextBox could not pass data to Access Database (Data Type: Number)

Tags: c#, ms-access

I will like to pass the Empty Textbox to Access Database (Data Type: Number) but it show error (Data type mismatch in criteria expression.)

Code below was used:

```
oleDBCommand.CommandText =
 "INSERT INTO tblRoutineChemAnalData ([Sample1 Vol]) VALUES (@Sample1Vol)";


oleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Sample1Vol", textBoxSample1.Text));
```

Note 1: If Access database field's Data Type set to **Short Text / Long Text**, code was **running fine** if the textboxSample1 was empty.

Note 2: If Access database field's Data Type set to **Number (Double)**, code was **running error** if the textboxSample1 was empty. Error description,

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

May I know what is the method to pass the empty textbox to Access Database that having **Number (double)** as Data Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the DBNull.Value like this.

```
double output = 0;
if (double.TryParse(textBoxSample1.Text, out output))
{
    oleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Sample1Vol", output));
}
else
{
    oleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Sample1Vol", DBNull.Value));
}
```

Make sure that the field `Sample1Vol` accepts null values.

Update: To use it for multiple fields, wrap it in a function like this.

```
private OleDbParameter CreateOleDbParameter(string parameterName, string parameterValue)
{
    double output = 0;
    if (double.TryParse(parameterValue, out output))
    {
        return new OleDbParameter(parameterName, output);
    }
    else
    {
        return new OleDbParameter(parameterName, DBNull.Value);
    }
}
```

Now use it like this

```
oleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(CreateOleDbParameter("@Sample1Vol", textBoxSample1.Text));
```

Comment: Tested the DBNull.Value and I do get the same error as well. (Data type mismatch in criteria expression.)

Comment: I had set the Field with Validation Rule (Blank) and Required (No). It should accept null value.

Comment: Thanks.. It is working by sending empty value to database (mean database will not show null, but just empty cell).

Comment: Is there any quick way to handle the code above as i have around 15 textbox require to go thru this empty value check?

Comment: you can wrap the whole thing in a function.

Comment: Awesome @naveen, your method make my day... Many Thanks.. :-)